Bounty removed days ago, but it still shows on the homepage
On SFF, I see a bountied question:

But in reality, the bounty was removed by a moderator 2 days ago. Why does it still show on the homepage and under "Bountied"?

I didn't remove the bounty, only the post notice. Moderator tools allow us to remove the notice (so that the bounty announcement isn't visible on the post itself) without cancelling the bounty altogether.

I didn't realize that you could cancel the message but leave the bounty. The lack of notice is confusing so I think you're not supposed to do that, but desperate times and whatnot.

Dunno about "not supposed to", but at least the system doesn't seem to be designed with that use case in mind. Tricks of the trade ;-)

Haha, I checked TagEngine if it was out of date, yep, still there. Okay, still there, then is it in elastic? yep, still there.  Okay, need to make sure elastic diff is happening correctly - checked SQL, yep, still there.  Figure out code path for mod menu to Remove Bounty vs Remove Post Notice and come back to report here only to refresh and find all of that info waiting for me already.  Ya'll are so smart.

If it's an issue that comes up a lot, maybe one of the mods can request a feature to remove bounty without refunding. Or suspend someone from opening bounties.

There's an xkcd about this... https://xkcd.com/530/  :D

@JourneymanGeek, haha, me tho
